# Retrieving the value of a java array in jsp

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, jstl

I have a java method that returns a String array.
Also there is a jsp page which has an array variable. How do I assign this jsp variable with the value returned by the java method?

I tried,

`<c:set var="list" value="<%= engine.getList(); %> "/>`

where `engine` is the java object. But this is not working. No values are getting stored.

### Java Code:

```
public String[] getCatEntId() {
    ArrayList<String> catEntIdArrList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Statement stmnt = null;
    String itemUrl = null;
    int i = 0;

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE ITEMID LIKE '%it%'";

    try {
        stmnt = getMySqlDbConn().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            itemUrl = rs.getString(1);
            String catalogId = itemUrl.substring((itemUrl.indexOf("productId=") + 10), (itemUrl.indexOf("productId=") + 15));
            System.out.println("Catalog Id : " + catalogId);
            catEntIdArrList.add(catalogId);
            i++;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return catEntIdArrList.toArray(new String[catEntIdArrList.size()]);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: you post only one line of code! There is no possibility to help you.

Comment: I am not using any servlet here.

Comment: Updated with java code

Answer (score 0):

Use JSTL Tag::

java code:

public List print() {

```
    ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    l.add("a");
    l.add("b");

 return l;

}
```

JSP Code::

```
  <c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
     ${item}<br>
  </c:forEach>
```

Comment: But how to populate ${list} with the values from `l`